# How to open a MatDialog with a lazy route

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to open components in a `MatDialog` that are from a lazy-loaded `NgModule`. What is the best way to do this?

Looking at angular.io, the Router seems to be the only way lazy-load modules.

So I was thinking about putting a [named router-outlet](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets) within a `MatDialog` and then opening the dialog and setting the named outlet to my lazy route. Is this the best way to do it?

How will `<router-outlet name="dialog"></router-outlet>` within a `MatDialog` component behave? If I reload the page and the dialog's `<router-outlet>` isn't displayed, what will happen? Do I need to wait on `MatDialog.open().afterOpen()` before setting the route?

Or is there an alternative way that doesn't use the Router?

Comment: Hi! Did you figure this out? How did you implement it? Will appreciate you comment on it :) thanks!

Comment: Agreed, did you discover any way to lazy load mat dialogs.

Comment: No, not yet. Unfortunately, this isn't high-priority enough for me to spend time on it at the moment. Hopefully someone will provide an answer or Angular will document it.

Comment: This article may help https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093 Please add an Answer here if you're able to get it working with MatDialog